# Get the last element of a 'request.security_lower_tf' array

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to get the last element of an array containing multiple daily `close` values, and using the code below I get an error. I believe it is related to the fact that the array has a zero size at the first bar of the chart. I tried in various ways, but I simply cannot pass over this error.

This will serve me to get the daily `close` value of the last trading day in a month (for monthly timeframes).

Alex

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

array<float> close_values = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close)

last_element_index = array.size(close_values)

//plot (last_element_index)
plot (array.get(close_values, last_element_index))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The error is caused on the first bar, which returns 0 elements.
So, the solution is to only retrieve the element when you have a non-zero array size.
Also, remember that arrays are zero-based, so the index of the last element in the array will always be one less than the array size.
This code will solve your issue, and explains the zero-based array issue step by step.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

array<float> close_values = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close)
var float element = na

array_size = array.size(close_values)

if array_size
    last_element_index = array_size - 1
    element := array.get(close_values, last_element_index)

// shorter version
// element := array_size ? array.get(close_values, array_size-1) : na

plot (element)
```